# Need help in understanding the Erlang code and what exactly it is doing

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am finding it difficult to decipher this code. I could understand that there is an instance of a data structure; is it a record or map?

The query is regarding the last two line of the code does it update the record with `Response` or does it check `message_code`?

```erlang
Response =
  #{header =>
      #{message_code => 'CONN_ESTABLISH_REQUEST',
        protocol_instance => ?MGMT_PROTOCOL_IDENTIFIER,
        transaction_identifier => 1},
    content => #{revision_list => [0]}
  },

#{header := #{message_code := 'CONN_ESTABLISH_CONFIRM'},
      content := Confirmation} = Response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a map, not a record.  (If it were a record, the record name would be between the `#` and the `{`.)

The last two lines perform a pattern match on the variable `Response`.  The code asserts that `Response` is a map containing at least two keys, `header` and `content`.  The value for `header` must be a map containing at least one key, `message_code`, whose value is `'CONN_ESTABLISH_CONFIRM'`.  The value for `content` will be stored in the variable `Confirmation`.
If the value of `Response` doesn't conform to *all* those requirements, this code will signal a `badmatch` error.

Note that the behaviour is different depending on whether the right hand side of `:=` contains:

- a constant
- an unbound variable
- a bound variable (a variable that already has a value)

If it is an unbound variable, the value for that key is simply stored in that variable.  If it is a bound variable, the value for that key *must* match the value of that variable, otherwise you get a `badmatch` error just like for a non-matching constant.

---

As you see, there are two different delimiters used, `=>` and `:=`.  When constructing a new map (such as the first expression in your example), you can only use `=>`, and when pattern matching, you can only use `:=`.  The idea is that they do different things: `=>` stores a key-value pair in the map, while `:=` extracts an existing key-value pair.

There is another case: updating an existing map.  In that case you can use both.  `=>` can be used to add a new key to the map, while `:=` can only be used to update an existing key, otherwise it signals a `badarg` error.  For example, if you wanted to add a "footer" to `Response`, you have to use `=>`:

```
NewResponse = Response#{footer => [some,data]},
%% this signals a badarg error:
NewResponse = Response#{footer := [some,data]},
```

while if you want to change the `content`, you can use either:

```
NewResponse = Response#{content := 42},
NewResponse = Response#{content => 42},
```

Comment: In the code posted above, it is definitely an atom, not a variable. It would need to start with a capital letter, e.g. `Confirmation`, to be a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation and its bang on Actually `Confirmation` is a unbound variable and not an atom

Comment: I have edited the code and its waiting in peer review

Comment: I would be more than thankful if you can help me in understanding this operator `:=` and is it like for an unbound variable it will copy the value of key `content` and for others it will check if there exists a similar pattern in `map`. 

That said `badMatch`  error if it happens will the value of key `content` be copied to `Confirmation`

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit. Hope that makes sense!